Boundedness of sum of sin(sin(n))
Playing with desmos I have accidentally noticed that the sequence of partial sums
$$\left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sin(\sin(n)) : N\geq 1 \right\}$$
is bounded.
However, I did not succeed in proving this statement.
My main idea was to show that there exists some constant $C > 0$ such that
$$\forall N \geq 1 \; \forall k \geq 0 \; : \left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{N} (\sin(n))^{2k+1}\right\vert \leq C$$
And then using the Taylor series
$$\sin(\sin(n)) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}(\sin(n))^{2m+1}$$
bound the partial sums defined above by $Ce$.
Could you please help me or suggest the techniques which may be useful in proving statements of this kind.

As to your approach, I think even the partial sums of $\sin(n)$ are $\underline{\text{un}}$bounded.

@mathworker21 I don't think that's true: Writing $\sin(n)$ as imaginary part of $e^{in}$, the partial sums evaluate to the imaginary part of a geometric sum $e^i \cdot \frac{e^{iN}-1}{e^i-1}$, where the numerator stays bounded by $2$ no matter how large $N$ gets.

@AchimKrause Thanks. Don't know why I thought otherwise.

This is true. It doesn't have much to do with the details of $\sin(\sin(\ ))$. Rather:
Theorem Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any smooth, $2 \pi$-periodic function with $\int_{z=0}^{2 \pi} f(z) dz=0$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$ is bounded independent of $N$.
There are two ingredients in the proof. First, we bound the coefficients of the Fourier series of $f$. We can write
$$f(\theta) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a_k e^{i k \theta}$$
where
$$a_k = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} e^{-i k \theta} f(\theta).$$
We have $a_0=0$ by the assumption on the integral of $f$. A standard strengthening of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma says that, if $f$ is $C^r$, then $a_k = o(1/k^r)$. (See, for example, here.) In our case, $f$ is smooth, so we obtain that
$$a_k = O(1/k^r) \ \text{for every}\ r. \tag{1}$$
So
$$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) = \sum_{k \neq 0} a_k \sum_{n=1}^N e^{ikn} = \sum_{k \neq 0} a_k \frac{e^{ik(N+1)} - e^{ik}}{e^{ik}-1} \tag{2} $$
where there is no $k=0$ term since $a_0=0$.
Now, Zeilberger and Zudilin proved (doi link, arXiv) that, for any integers $k$ and $\ell \neq 0$, we have
$$|\pi - k/\ell| \geq c/\ell^{7.11}$$
for some $c>0$. So
$$|k - \ell \pi| \geq c/\ell^{6.11} \geq c'/k^{6.11}$$
for some other constant $c'$. So
$$\frac{e^{ik(N+1)} - e^{ik}}{e^{ik}-1} = O(k^{6.11}). \tag{3}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(3)$, the summand in (2) is $O(k^{6.11-r})$ for every $r$, and thus in particular is $O(k^{-2})$. So the sum in $(2)$ is bounded, independent of $N$.

This is a great answer. It shows how the ultimate point is that $\pi$ is not well approximated by rational numbers.

Thanks! I've been wondering whether I can find a $\theta$ for which the sums of $\sin(\sin(n \theta))$ are unbounded. The tricky thing is that, if $\sin(\sin(\phi))$ is close to its maximum, then $\sin(\sin(3 \phi))$ is close to its minimum, so you tend to get a lot of cancellation.

Mr. David, thank you very much for your solution, the theorems you stated are really nice and useful ! I did not know about them before.

If I understand correctly, the only information needed about $\pi$ is that its irrationality measure is finite.

Seems that ZZ's bound is overkill for this theorem. How cheaper is it to prove a coarser bound, good enough to do the job? (Differently put: do I have a reasonable chance to make a problem out of this wonderful answer?)

The earliest result I can find of this form is Mahler (1953), "On the approximation of $\pi$", who obtains $|\pi - p/q| > c q^{-42}$ and indicates that the exponent can be improved to $30$ but omits the details. https://ems.press/content/book-chapter-files/27418 The only earlier work that he cites is Feldman (1951) "The approximation of certain transcendental numbers. I. Approximation of logarithms of algebraic numbers" ; I wasn't able to extract a specific bound from Feldman. @PseudoNeo

So it seems that every irrational number has some constant telling us how irrational it is, pi has an irrational value 6.11, e might have a different value, and the sum in question is bounded if the value is greater than 2?

Some corrections: The irrationality measure of $\pi$ is known to be $\leq 7.11$, we don't know how much smaller it might be. All irrational numbers have irrationality measure $\geq 2$. The proof above works with any number with finite irrationality measure. A number with infinite irrationality measure is called a Liouville number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number .

I think one can use similar tricks as in the accepted answer at Is the series $\sum_n|\sin n|^n/n$ convergent?.
To start with, I don't think one can hope for a constant bound $C$ as you hoped. Indeed,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n)^{2k+1} = \frac{1}{(2i)^{2k+1}} \sum_{n=1}^N (e^{ni}-e^{-ni})^{2k+1}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{(2i)^{2k+1}} \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{l=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{l} e^{(2k+1-2l)in}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{(2i)^{2k+1}} \sum_{l=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{l} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{(2k+1-2l)in}$$
$$
= \frac{1}{(2i)^{2k+1}} \sum_{l=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{l} e^{(2k+1-2l)i}\frac{e^{(2k+1-2l)iN}-1}{e^{(2k+1-2l)i}-1}.
$$
This stays bounded for large $N$, as the numerators are bounded by $2$. However, the denominator here is controlled by how close $2k+1-2l$ gets to a multiple of $2\pi$, and so is related to rational approximations of $\pi$. So I believe these sums will not admit a uniform constant bound. But as in the linked answer, there is some lower bound on the quality of rational approximations of $\pi$. Let us write
$$
d_k = \min_{0\leq l\leq 2k+1, q\in \mathbb{Z}} |2k+1-2l-2q\pi|.
$$
Thus, $d_k = 2q \cdot |\frac{2p+1}{2q}-\pi|$ where $\frac{2p+1}{2q}$ is the best approximation to $\pi$ with odd numerator $|2p+1|\leq 2k+1$ and even denominator. By the linked answer, we have
$$
d_k > 2q\frac{1}{(2q)^{\mu+\varepsilon}} > \frac{1}{(2q)^{\mu+\varepsilon-1}} > \frac{1}{(2k+1)^7}.
$$
Now $|e^{(2k+1-2l)-1}-1| > C\cdot d_k$ for some global constant $C$ and all $0\leq l\leq 2k+1$, and so we obtain a bound
$$
\left| \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n)^{2k+1} \right| < \frac{2}{C d_k} < \frac{1}{C} (2k+1)^7.
$$
This yields a uniform upper bound for $|\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(\sin(n))|$ of the form
$$
\frac{1}{C} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k+1)^7}{(2k+1)!},
$$
which is finite.

Dear Achim Krause, I am grateful for you solution. It is also great ! Thank you for teaching me new tricks :)
